# Resizing iframe? - Webkit or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, webkit, resize

is it possible the proportions within an iframe? e.g. 100%, 50%, 25%, ...

I would like to implement a "magnifying glass" for a webpage or iframe. It does not have to be implemented in Javascript within a website, but even a desktop solution would be great.

Is this a possibility? or would it be incredibly complicated?

---

Any ideas? Help would be amazing =)

Comment: You may set width and height on an iframe element as on any html element. But I'm guessing that's not what you are looking for. Here's a reference to the iframe specification so you may see what you can and can not do with iframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe .

Comment: Do you mean a text/image zoom like this? http://css-tricks.com/anythingzoomer-jquery-plugin/ or do you want to zoom an entire page?

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you can use the `-moz-transform` CSS property to zoom, using the `scale()` value. Note that this doesn't change the amount of space that the element takes up on the page.